# In what timeline and what year does the new Will & Grace take place?

Tags: will-and-grace

I watched *Will & Grace* sporadically during its original run. Aside from the gay characters on the main cast, it was a rather run-of-the-mill sitcom, in my opinion.

But I do remember very clearly that I watched the original series finale, and that it skipped ahead to the future, when Will's daughter and Grace's son meet and fall in love. Or maybe it was Will's son and Grace's daughter. Either way, there was a time jump.

The new *Will & Grace* series has been referred to as a "reboot" by some entertainment reporters, which suggests a break with the continuity of the original series, or at the very least a resetting of the timeline (kind of like how on *Superman* Clark Kent is now a blogger, or how on *Supergirl* Catco is a multimedia empire rather than the publisher of a newspaper).

Another possibility, which is the one that I would choose if it was up to me, would be to simply stay in the timeline established by the original series, but have the new series pick up in the present day. I believe this would mean Will's child and Grace's child are not even teenagers yet, but maybe the stories can work towards the eventually shown in the original series finale.

Or maybe the writers do something I haven't even thought of, or maybe they're not taking continuity as seriously as I am. Does anyone know today, or will we simply have to wait to the new series premiere to even begin to answer this question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about a future work so answers are likely to be solely opinion based

Comment: Actually, as someone who writes for a spoiler site, there usually is quite a lot of interviews with spoilers and some clarification from EPs prior to season/series premieres these days, especially for high profile shows.

Answer (score 2):

So there was an interview with Vanity Fair from the end of July that stated that the finale (future scenes) would be addressed, but almost in a way as if they were in the same timeline, but maybe with some minor altercations or a creative way to use the finale back onto the revival. I have not yet seen an article that states that the whole thing is a full-fledged reboot and I would think if it were, they wouldn't care about addressing the finale in any capacity--I would think they would ignore it.

> When asked to address any head-scratching fans, Kohan jokingly told E!
>   News, “Keep scratching.” Mutchnick, however, was more forthcoming: “I
>   would say this,” he offered. “We’ve just come out of a story camp that
>   lasted about three months. That’s where we break and write all of the
>   episodes that we will be filming in August or whenever we start. **I
>   will tell you that almost more than anything, more time went into
>   figuring out how are we going to reintroduce the show and what were
>   the rules going to be and how were we going to address that finale . .
>   . And we can tell you this much: They are very much living in that
>   apartment in 2017 in the month of September, on the 28th of September
>   at 9:00. That’s when you’re going to meet up with them again,** and they
>   are going to explain to you exactly what happened, so you know the
>   rules moving forward and you won’t feel like anything is left open.”https://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2017/06/will-and-grace-revival-series-finale

Then there is this a few days later from EW...

**~~~~~~~~WARNING - MORE SPOILERS in EW Article!!~~~~~~~~**

> “When the decision was made to bring the series back, we were like,
>   well, we left them with kids, right?” adds executive producer/creator
>   David Kohan. “And if they have children, then it has to be about them
>   being parents, ‘cause presumably it would be a priority in their
>   lives. And if it wasn’t a priority in their lives, then they’re still
>   parents, they’re just bad parents, right? We frankly did not want to
>   see them being either good parents or bad parents. We wanted them to
>   be Will and Grace.”
>
> It will be Groundhog Day, too, for Jack (Sean Hayes) and Karen (Megan
>   Mullally). Though they were last seen living together with Rosario the
>   maid in the finale, Jack will return as Will and Grace’s omnipresent
>   neighbor while Karen will still get her drink on and live in that
>   mansion. Will and Grace’s careers will be the same, and Jack the actor
>   will be teaching his own craft called “Jackting.http://ew.com/tv/2017/08/02/will-grace-revival-finale/”

I came back to make an edit. The **Press Release from 9.01** is out. It seems to confirm that this does in fact take place, *11 Years Later*...

> "WILL & GRACE" "11 YEARS LATER"
>
> 09/28/2017 (09:00PM - 09:30PM) (Thursday) : PREMIERE - AFTER 11 YEARS,
>   THE HIGHLY ANTICIPATED RETURN OF "WILL & GRACE" - We pick up with Will
>   (Eric McCormack), Grace (Debra Messing), Jack (Sean Hayes), and Karen
>   (Megan Mullally) **11 years since we last saw them. Will and Grace both
>   falter when their political beliefs are put to the test. Jack and
>   Karen help Will and Grace hide their secret shame from each other, but
>   the truth finally comes out.**
>   http://www.spoilertv.com/2017/09/will-grace-episode-901-11-years-later.html